# I'm trying to import packages into Jupyter but I'm getting module errors

Tags: anaconda, jupyter

I've installed packages through the anaconda prompt but when I go into Jupyter to import a package for example numpy, I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

I also get a window that says:
Error Starting Kernel 'module' object is not callable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYptf.jpg)

I tried installing packages through anaconda prompt.

Comment: Did you load your anaconda environment in Jupyter? Use the following command ---

!conda activate your_environment_name

Comment: Anaconda is an excellent tool for managing your projects because you can have an environment for each of them. However, it is complex and you have to put in some time to learn it. The Anaconda prompt, where you state you installed (you state it twice for some reason?), doesn't necessarily install to each environment where you will run Jupyter so you have to specifically install to the environment as Shilaja's comment is urging you towards. Or you can install from within Jupyter where you have an active `.ipynb` file running so that it insures the installation occurs in the matching ...

Comment: <continued> Based on [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/numpy) and [use of the proper magic install command](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez), you'd make a new cell in the notebook where you want to run the import statement and run the following in that cell: `%conda install conda-forge::numpy`. Let it completely run and then restart the kernel when it finishes successfully. Then try the import statement. Keep in mind because you opted for the Anaconda Distribution that is your primary package manager and you...

Comment: <continued> want to endeavor to use Anaconda/conda to install always. Only ever resort to `pip` when you encounter something that doesn't have a conda recipe. Although it is slower to carry out installs, conda is more thorough and using it correctly will result in more robust and portable environments.